# How much help to provide someone who will not learn on their own

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, training

I have learned a lot about Selenium by reading Selenium Guidebook, and then spending over two years writing tests, researching issues, and finding ways of doing complex things. I have tests that are parameterized for data driven, tests that are parallelized, and complex Jenkins jobs.

My team recently merged with another team, and the QA from that team knows perhaps a third of what I know. My boss has asked us to work together on our collective test frameworks. I have been pairing with the QA weekly, and during those meetings, I have been explaining things like how to use environment variables, how to structure the project(s) using Page Objects model, etc - things I feel are very elementary.

I mentioned several times to him that our organization has access to the Selenium Guidebook and recommended that he step through the book.

The QA is excellent at marketing himself as an expert, but when we work together, this is clearly not the case. He has been very passionate about advocating that we change our test architecture (from junit to testng) or that we should use Maven to encrypt sensitive data (instead of using env variables). I wouldn't want his advice to create unnecessary work.

Should I mention this to our boss? Would that be seen as tattling? Am I wrong to expect a team member to do their own learning before leaning on me? Should I cancel further meetings with him until he has completed some self-study?

Comment: Everyone needs to start somewhere

Comment: This is question not about QA, but about workplace politics. Similar question were asked and have excellent answers on https://workplace.stackexchange.com/ I am writing this not to chase you away (thanks for thinking about us first), but to get you better answers.

Comment: like: https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/107522/manager-gives-credit-to-senior-collegue-instead-of-me , https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/18496/how-to-gain-respect-from-more-experienced-co-workers https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/84512/how-to-deal-with-a-new-inexperienced-and-hostile-colleague and more. Just search around Workplace SE.

Comment: @PeterMasiar while some parts of this question may belong in workplace stack exchange, i found the QA related specifics quite interesting relating to Maven, TestNG, JUnit i and i think it should still stay on SQA forum.

Comment: @BrianMcCarthy  I have no problem keeping this question here. I even upvoted it. I just considered beneficial (to OP) to notify OP what many and better answers are on Workplace SE, and I linked few related.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to workplace.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I wouldn't want his advice to be create unnecessary work.

First of all I would ask your mate to give me a vision on what would be the value of the changes, since Maven or TestNG vs JUnit issues are not the ones which might be cleared out using Selenium Guidebook, since Selenium is mostly about interaction with UI, and Maven and unit-test frameworks are mostly about execution environment. It might turn out that the changes are worth introducing.

> Should I cancel further meetings with him until he has completed some self-study?

Don't even think about this. Use the meetings to bring his knowledge in line with yours. You have to work together and both of you have to elaborate the effective ways of delivering value to your company

> The guy is excellent at marketing himself as an expert

Take him over to your side. Use his "marketing" skills to advocate the changes you think are good to be introduced in the company processes. Give in to some of his ideas so that he would accept some of yours.

> Should I mention this to our boss?

I wouldn't unless there is a real risk of not delivering some critical feature. Don't give your boss another headache. Better suggest your boss that **you take a leadership** in the test automation. Say that there are different opinions and there should be one person who can consolidate all of them.

> Am I wrong to expect a team member to do their own learning before leaning on me?

Having no knowledge does not let you understand what level of knowledge would be sufficient for the job. So a more junior developer might consider that the level of knowledge they have is enough. You, however, with more experience, can provide leadership (again). This might also help give you career a kick.

Comment: removed some of the 'man' stuff to make it more gender neutral so applies to more situations for others and also to reduce unnecessary gender references which may bother some.

Comment: Yup, thanks Michael! I was thinking about that, however my English is far not perfect :) I though that "a man" can be used in the meaning of "one person".

Comment: Wow! Great advice regarding Maven, TestNG, JUnit, and more bees with honey! lol @AlexeyR

Comment: The answer to this question did demand a lot of thoughtfulness and wisdom. Really liked the way you answered it, Alexey. Awesome!